# Android Studio emulator turns off USB in my PC

Tags: android, android-emulator, usb, android-studio-2.1

I have wierd problem. When I turn on build-in android emulator (Nexus 5 with 5.0 Lolipop) in Android Studio (v.2.1.2) after some random period of time my mouse freezes, then turns off, next is keyboard, and everything on USB. It happens randomly, sometimes I'm working few hours in AS and no problems, but sometimes it happens just after first launch of emulator. What could cause that? Where should I look for reason of that?

I'm working on Ubuntu x64 14.04 kernel 4.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the emulator takes too much of RAM memory when starts running and results in hang of the devices.
You can use an alternative method for this 
You can open the Compiler > Gradle options and enable Offline mode, which will tell Gradle to ignore update-to-date checks"

Comment: I have turned on 'Offline work' in Gradle settings and emulator starts, but after about 3 minutes it happened again, so it didn't help :( 
I have 16 GB of RAM in my computer, I never thought it will be not enough for such things.
I have also forget about WiFi, it also turns off with USB. Only restart helps.